How many Ancient and Somber Ancient Dragon Smithing Stones are available in Shadow of the Erdtree?
In the base game of Elden Ring, these items are highly constrained - there are only 13 and 8 of each respectively, highly limiting the number of max level weapons that one can acquire.
With dozens of new weapons available in Shadow of the Erdtree, presumably there are new max level smithing stones to max these items out. Are they similarly quantity constrained as they were in the base game? If so, how many of them can be found?

https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/somber+ancient+dragon+smithing+stone
Emphasis mine:

There are only eight Somber Ancient Dragon Smithing Stones in the base game and six in Shadow of the Erdtree, with no way to infinitely farm them aside from continually going into New Game Plus.

https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Ancient+Dragon+Smithing+Stone

8 Ancient Dragon Smithing Stones can be found in Shadow of the Erdtree.

